# Replacing text in nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jQuery that counts how many sections there are on a page and which block is which.

The following sample demonstrates this:

```js
$(function() {
 var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
    $(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
    $(".question-number").each(function(index) {
       console.log(index + 1);
       $(this).append(index + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
```

However, you can see that the result is backwards. It should read "1 of 4", "2 of 4" and so on.

I tried a few different things:

`.text()`

```js
$(function() {
 var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
    $(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
    $(".question-number").each(function(index) {
       console.log(index + 1);
       $(this).text(index + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work cause it overwrites everything

`.html()`

```js
$(function() {
 var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
    $(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
    $(".question-number").each(function(index) {
       console.log(index + 1);
       $(this).html(index + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total">of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></span></div>
</div>
```

Same result.

Why is the order backwards? How can I insert the value above the markup for the total so it reads "x of y"?

Comment: Your HTML is doing that. Fix: close the first `span` immediately, before the word  "of", not after the other `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is doing that. Fix: close the first `span` immediately, before the word "of", not after the other `span`, and then target the first and second `span` in your code:

```js
$(function() {
 var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
    $(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
    $(".question-total").each(function(index) {
       console.log(index + 1);
       $(this).append(index + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span> of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span> of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span> of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span> of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restructure your HTML a bit by closing the first span.

Then target the span by class to set the text:

```js
$(function() {
  var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
  $(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
  $(".question-number").each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + 1);
    $(this).find('.question-total').text(index + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span>of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span>of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span>of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number"><span class="question-total"></span>of <span class="question-total__integer"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of `.append()`

```js
var totalQuestionAmount = $(".question").length;
$(".question-total__integer").text(totalQuestionAmount);
$(".question-number").each(function(index) {
  console.log(index + 1);
  $(this).prepend(index + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number">
    <span class="question-total">of 
      <span class="question-total__integer"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number">
    <span class="question-total">of 
      <span class="question-total__integer"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number">
    <span class="question-total">of 
      <span class="question-total__integer"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <div class="question-number">
  <span class="question-total">of 
  <span class="question-total__integer"></span>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```